# OpenGL ES: change part of matrix-vector in glsl from client side

Tags: glsles, opengl-es-3.0

I have this uniform in glsl

```
uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix[64];
```

that is filled with 64 matrices

its used to transform 64 shapes in my game. It works good!!!

My question if its possible change a part of this matrix-vector if I for instance want to rotate or resize a certain sprite? Could I use the method:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(int location, int count, boolean transpose, float[] value, int offset)
```

?

I do not understand the offset argument, I thought was it used as an offset into the matrix-vec in glsl but obviously not?

```
  GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandleEyes, 1, false, mMVPMatrixEyes, 1);
```

IF I change the offset argument I get an exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: length - offset < count*16 < needed
                                                                                 at android.opengl.GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(Native Method)
```

What is the solution to this issue? Should I instead focus om making the change on the GPU-side? But could a uniform be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform arrays in glsl are guaranteed to have consecutive locations. The uniform `u_MVPMatrix[i]` thus has the location `mMVPMatrixHandleEyes + i`. This location can be used to set a single matrix (or multiple consecutive ones) by passing it to `glUniformMatrix4fv`.

The offset parameter, in contrast, is an offset into the float[] array passed, not into the glsl array.

Comment: thanks I'll look into this as soon as possible :-) May accept an upvote if it works